# C# Word OpenXml SDK - Adding text to a run trims spaces

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to add text runs to an existing paragraph in Word using the OpenXml SDK, but every time I do this it ends up "trimming" the text which I add.

**For example**

```
 Run newRun = newRun();
 newRun.AppendChild(new Text("Hello "));
 paragraph.AppendChild(newRun);

 Run newRun = newRun();
 newRun.AppendChild(new Text(" World"));
 paragraph.AppendChild(newRun);

 // the resulting paragraph contains "HelloWorld" as the text
```

I've also checked the XML of the resulting Run which gets generated, which clearly includes the "space" character:

```
<w:t xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\">Hello  </w:t>
```

I've tried injecting '\u0020' unicode values, as well as an "empty" run which just contains a single space, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know the trick to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SpaceProcessingModeValues` enum.

```cs
var text   = new Text("Hello ");

text.Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve;
```

With a couple of extension methods you can handle it automatically, and also line breaks:

```cs
public static Text Append(this Run run, string text)
{
    Text lastText = null;

    if (text == null)
    {
        lastText = new Text();

        run.Append(lastText);

        return lastText;
    }

    var lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None );

    for (int index = 0; index < lines.Length; index++)
    {
        if (index != 0)
            run.AppendBreak();

        var line = lines[index];

        lastText = new Text(line);

        if (line.StartsWith(" ") || line.EndsWith(" "))
            lastText.Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve;

        run.Append(lastText);
    }

    return lastText;
}

public static void AppendBreak(this Run run)
{
    run.Append(new Break());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rolling my eyes at how typical that I find the answer 5 minutes after posting (having been trying for hours)

The answer is to add the XML *xml:space="preserve"* attribute to the Text element, otherwise spaces are trimmed.

```
newRun.InnerXml = $"<w:t xml:space=\"preserve\" xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\">{text}</w:t>";
```